# How should one implement "is.error()" for R, to identify and parse errors?

Tags: r, error-handling

I am trying to test if objects are the results of errors.  The use case primarily arises via a `foreach()` loop that produces an error (although, for testing, it seems enough to just assign a `simpleError()` to a variable), and I'm puzzled about how to identify when that has occurred: how can I test that a given object is, in fact, an error?  Once I've determined that it is an error, what else can I extract, besides a message?  Perhaps I'm missing something about R's error handling facilities, as it seems necessary to write an error object testing function *de novo*.

Here are two examples, one using `foreach`, with the `.errorhandling` argument set to `pass`.  I have begun to use that as the default for large scale or unattended processing, in the event of an anomaly in a slice of data.  Such anomalies are rare, and not worth crashing the entire for loop (especially if that anomaly occurs at the end, which appears to be the default behavior of my `murphysListSortingAlgorithm()` ;-)). Instead, *post hoc* detection is desired.

```
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(2)
results = foreach(ix = 1:10, .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar%{
    if(ix == 6){
        stop("Perfect")
    } 
    if(ix == 7){
        stop("LuckyPrime")
    } else {
        return(ix)
    }
}
```

For simplicity, here is a very simple error (by definition):

```
a = simpleError("SNAFU")
```

While there does not seem to be a command like `is.error()`, and commands like `typeof()` and `mode()` seem to be pointless, the best I've found is to use `class()` or `attributes()`, which give attributes that are indicative of an error.  How can I use these in a manner guaranteed to determine that I've got an error and to fully process that error?  For instance `a$message` returns `SNAFU`, but `a$call` is `NULL`.  Should I expect to be able to extract anything useful from, say, `res[[6]]$call`?

---

Note 1: In case one doesn't have multicore functionality to reproduce the first example, I should point out that `results[[6]]` isn't the same as `simpleError("Perfect")`:

```
> b = simpleError("Perfect")
> identical(results[[6]], b)
[1] FALSE
> results[[6]]
<simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): Perfect>
> b
<simpleError: Perfect>
```

This demonstrates why I can't (very naively) test if the list element is a vanilla `simpleError`.

Note 2.  I am aware of `try` and `tryCatch`, and use these in some contexts.  However, I'm not entirely sure how I can use them to post-process the output of, say, a `foreach` loop.  For instance, the `results` object in the first example: it does not appear to me to make sense to process its elements with a `tryCatch` wrapper.  For the RHS of the operation, i.e. the `foreach()` loop, I'm not sure that `tryCatch` will do what I intend, either.  I can use it to catch an error, but I suppose I need to get the message and insert the processing at that point.  I see two issues: every loop would need to be wrapped with a `tryCatch()`, negating part of the `.errorhandling` argument, and I remain unable to later post-process the `results` object.  If that's the only way to do this processing, then it's the solution, but that implies that errors can't be identified and processed in a similar way to many other R objects, such as matrices, vectors, data frames, etc.

---

Update 1.  I've added an additional stop trigger in the `foreach` loop, to give two different messages to identify and parse, in case this is helpful.

Update 2.  I'm selecting Richie Cotton's answer.  It seems to be the most complete explanation of what I should look for, though a complete implementation requires several other bits of code (and a recent version of R). Most importantly, he points out that there are 2 types of errors we need to keep in mind, which is especially important in being thorough.  See also the comments and answers by others in order to fully develop your own `is.error()` test function; the answer I've given can be a useful start when looking for errors in a list of results, and the code by Richie is a good starting point for the test functions.

Comment: Have you tried `try` and/or `tryCatch`?

Comment: @HongOoi I have used these in other contexts, but I'm not clear on how I can use them to detect and parse errors: Suppose that I have a lot of values that are not errors - what would I do?  Still, it's an interesting avenue, and I will update the question.

Comment: I'm also confused why `tryCatch` doesn't work here.  I wouldn't necessarily think of errors as objects....

Comment: @gsk3 I very much welcome a solution demonstrating `tryCatch`.  :)  Perhaps I'm missing something. Like you, I don't necessarily think of errors as objects, but I do think of the values of `results` as objects, and one of them is a `simpleError` - why shouldn't we be able test that that is the case?

Comment: Alright I was unfamiliar with simpleError.  Must have been running `gsk3sMurphySOpostGenerator`.

Comment: @gsk3  `simpleError` is nothing. Just wait'll you see `motherOfAllErrors`. It requires a very special operating system famous for its errors...

Comment: In the beginning, there was `condition`.  And `condition` begat `BlueScreenOfDeath`, who lay with `motherOfAllErrors` and begat `error`.  `error` wandered the parched earth for many years, until meeting `simpleton`, and together they begat `simpleError`.  And life was for the `condition`s.

Comment: @gsk3 We have a candidate for `fortunes()`.  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only two types of errors that you are likely to see in the wild are `simpleError`s like you get here, and `try-error`s that are the result of wrapping some exception throwing code in a call to `try`.  It is possible for someone to create their own error class, though these are rare and should be based upon one of those two classes.  In fact (since R2.14.0) `try-error`s contain a `simpleError`:

```
e <- try(stop("throwing a try-error"))
attr(e, "condition")
```

To detect a `simpleError` is straightforward.

```
is_simple_error <- function(x) inherits(x, "simpleError")
```

The equivalent for try catch errors is

```
is_try_error <- function(x) inherits(x, "try-error")
```

So here, you can inspect the results for problems  by applying this to your list of results.

```
the_fails <- sapply(results, is_simple_error)
```

Likewise, returning the message and call are one-liners.  For convenience, I've converted the call to a character string, but you might not want that.

```
get_simple_error_message <- function(e) e$message
get_simple_error_call <- function(e) deparse(e$call)

sapply(results[the_fails], get_simple_error_message)
sapply(results[the_fails], get_simple_error_call)
```

Comment: Can you post the output you get from the first `attr()`?  I get `NULL` and am not sure what to make of that in relation to what you mentioned about containing a `simpleError`, esp. relative to `attributes(e)`.

Comment: For me, `attr(e, "condition")` returns `<simpleError in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): throwing a try-error>`.

Comment: Aha: I am using {2.13.1, 2.13.2}, while the behavior you're seeing is new with 2.14.0 (per the [NEWS](http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS.html) file).  I guess it's time to say goodbye to the old, familiar bugs and welcome new ones to my life.  Aka, time to upgrade.  :)

Comment: Accepted this answer because you've pointed out that there are 2 types of errors to query, not just the vanilla one that my code would check.

Answer (score 3):

From ?simpleError:

> Conditions are objects inheriting from the abstract class condition.
>   Errors and warnings are objects inheriting from the abstract
>   subclasses error and warning. The class simpleError is the class used
>   by stop and all internal error signals. Similarly, simpleWarning is
>   used by warning, and simpleMessage is used by message. The
>   constructors by the same names take a string describing the condition
>   as argument and an optional call. The functions conditionMessage and
>   conditionCall are generic functions that return the message and call
>   of a condition.

So `class(a)` returns:

```
[1] "simpleError" "error"       "condition"
```

So a simple function:

```
is.condition <- function(x) {
  require(taRifx)
  last(class(x))=="condition"
}
```

As @flodel notes, replacing the function body with `inherits(x,"condition")` is more robust.

Comment: Where is this `last()` function you speak of?  :)  Nonetheless, try `f=6;class(f) = "condition"` - there's no guarantee that this detects only errors.  Now we're looking at Type I and Type II errors.  ;-)

Comment: (continued) I'm willing to consider that testing "first()" (aka `head(...,1)`, is `simpleError` is a useful test, which is what I am thinking of doing.  Still, it seems that parsing the errors is about going after the `$message` element, with some problems arising in `$call` - I'm not sure what that does.

Comment: Oops.  Fixed that :-).  My reading of `?conditions` is that if it's a warning or an error then the highest class is "condition", and if it's an error of some kind the second highest class is always "error."  So maybe test for that rather than simpleError, since it'll catch more errors?

Comment: That's an interesting point.  I hadn't thought about a hierarchy of classes, but this gets at my concern that there might be some, errm, Type II errors (no pun intended).  I'll have to read this more carefully - I'm just not well versed in R's errors.  :)  Btw, shouldn't `require()` be inside the function?

Comment: Yeah.  The whole "abstract class" thing makes me a little nervous without understanding what exactly an "abstract class" is.  Moved require inside.  Was conceiving of is.condition as being used in a package which listed taRifx among its dependencies.  Of course, in that context probably better to just write it without using `last` and avoid loading unnecessary stuff :-)

Comment: I agree about the abstract class issue - I'm not sure I can trust an error detector that I'd write, without mastering this class issue.

Comment: It's true.  Class heirarchies are really one of the fundamental problems facing us as a society today.

Comment: inherits(x, "condition") may be more appropriate.

Comment: @flodel That's an interesting suggestion.  I've taken a stab at using it to test for errors, in an answer below.  gsk3: This may begin to nail the detection of errors.  I'm not yet sure if there's a clean way to parse the errors, e.g. both the message and the `call` value; plus, we're still working on `simpleError`s.  I wonder what the `gnarlyErrors` are like.

Answer (score 2):

Using @flodel's suggestion about `inherits()`, which gets at the abstract class inheritance mentioned by @gsk3, here's my current solution:

```
is.error.element <- function(x){
    testError   <- inherits(x, "error")
    if(testError == TRUE){
        testSimple  <- inherits(x, "simpleError")
        errMsg      <- x$message
    } else {
        testSimple  <- FALSE
        errMsg      <- NA
    }
    return(data.frame(testError, testSimple, errMsg, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}

is.error <- function(testObject){
    quickTest <- is.error.element(testObject)
    if(quickTest$testError == TRUE){
        return(quickTest)
    } else {
        return(lapply(testObject, is.error.element))
    }
}
```

Here are results, made pretty via `ldply` for the `results` list:

```
> ldply(is.error(results))
   testError testSimple     errMsg
1      FALSE      FALSE       <NA>
2      FALSE      FALSE       <NA>
3      FALSE      FALSE       <NA>
4      FALSE      FALSE       <NA>
5      FALSE      FALSE       <NA>
6       TRUE       TRUE    Perfect
7       TRUE       TRUE LuckyPrime
8      FALSE      FALSE       <NA>
9      FALSE      FALSE       <NA>
10     FALSE      FALSE       <NA>

> is.error(a)
  testError testSimple errMsg
1      TRUE       TRUE  SNAFU
```

This still seems rough to me, not least because I haven't extracted a meaningful `call` value, and the outer function, `isError()`, might not do well on other structures.  I suspect that this could be improved with `sapply` or another member of the `*apply` or `*ply` (`plyr`) families.

Answer (score 1):

I use try and catch as described in this question:
[How do I save warnings and errors as output from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948361)

The idea is that each item in the loop returns a list with three elements: the return value, any warnings, and any errors.  The result is a list of lists that can then be queried to find out not only the values from each item in the loop, but which items in the loop had warnings or errors.

In this example, I would do something like this:

```
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(2)
results = foreach(ix = 1:10, .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar%{
  catchToList({
    if(ix == 6){
        stop("Perfect")
    } 
    if(ix == 7){
        stop("LuckyPrime")
    } else {
        ix
    }
  })
}
```

Then I would process the results like this

```
> ok <- sapply(results, function(x) is.null(x$error))
> which(!ok)
[1] 6 7
> sapply(results[!ok], function(x) x$error)
[1] "Perfect"    "LuckyPrime"
> sapply(results[ok], function(x) x$value)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  8  9 10
```

It would be fairly straightforward to give the result from `catchToList` a class and overload some accessing functions to make the above syntax easier, but I haven't found a real need for that yet.

Comment: +1 Many very interesting ideas here and from that link and the further related Q&A posts to which it is linked.

Comment: Martin's answer in the link is really good, but not very robust for passing of formulas. :/

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: True.  Perhaps the `catchToList` solution in the OP (at that link) would work better?