# Disregarding simple warnings/errors in tryCatch()

Tags: r, warnings, try-catch

I'm a huge fan of `tryCatch()`. However, until today I never really paid attention to the distinction between simple and regular warnings/errors and thus I don't really know how to handle them.

### Actual question

What I'd like to know is how to tell `tryCatch` ([see help file](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/conditions.html)) that simple warnings are OK and that it should return the result of `expr` instead of jumping to the `warning` section.

Below you'll find a reproducible example

---

### No `tryCatch` >> no warning

```
require("forecast")
y   <- ts(c(6178, 7084, 8162, 8462, 9644, 10466, 10748, 9963, 8194, 6848, 7027, 7269, 6775, 7819, 8371, 9069, 10248, 11030, 10882, 10333, 9109, 7685, 7602, 8350, 7829, 8829, 9948, 10638, 11253, 11424, 11391, 10665, 9396, 7775, 7933, 8186, 7444, 8484, 9864, 10252, 12282, 11637, 11577, 12417, 9637, 8094, 9280, 8334, 7899, 9994, 10078, 10801, 12950, 12222, 12246, 13281, 10366, 8730, 9614, 8639, 8772, 10894, 10455, 11179, 10588, 10794, 12770, 13812, 10857, 9290, 10925, 9491, 8919, 11607, 8852, 12537, 14759, 13667, 13731, 15110, 12185, 10645, 12161, 10840, 10436, 13589, 13402, 13103, 14933, 14147, 14057, 16234, 12389, 11595, 12772))
out <- forecast::auto.arima(x=y)
> out
Series: y 
ARIMA(4,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2     ar3      ar4      ma1
      0.6768  -0.2142  0.5025  -0.7125  -0.8277
s.e.  0.0749   0.0889  0.0874   0.0735   0.0485

sigma^2 estimated as 915556:  log likelihood=-780.33
AIC=1572.65   AICc=1573.62   BIC=1587.91
```

### `tryCatch` >> simple warning

When I wrap it with `tryCatch`, it detects a simple warning that will cause my `expr` block to be "skipped" in favor of the `warning` section. Thus the function does not return the estimation result, but the simple warning.

```
mod <- tryCatch(
    out <- forecast::auto.arima(x=y),
    error=function(e) {
        print(e)
    },
    warning=function(w) {
        print(w)
    }
)

> mod 
<simpleWarning in kpss.test(x): p-value smaller than printed p-value>
```

### Current workaround

```
if (any(class(mod) == "simpleWarning")) {
    mod <- forecast::auto.arima(x=y)
}

> mod
Series: y 
ARIMA(4,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2     ar3      ar4      ma1
      0.6768  -0.2142  0.5025  -0.7125  -0.8277
s.e.  0.0749   0.0889  0.0874   0.0735   0.0485

sigma^2 estimated as 915556:  log likelihood=-780.33
AIC=1572.65   AICc=1573.62   BIC=1587.91
```

Comment: I often find it helpful to save both the warnings and the output, and decide what to do later.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4948361/210673.  This uses the same methods that @MartinMorgan suggests.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're looking for the difference between `tryCatch`, which catches a condition and continues evaluation from the environment where the tryCatch was defined, versus `withCallingHandlers`, which allows you to 'handle' a condition and then continue on from the location where the condition occurred. Take a look at `warning` (or the help page for warning, but that's less fun), especially the lines

```
    withRestarts({
        .Internal(.signalCondition(cond, message, call))
        .Internal(.dfltWarn(message, call))
    }, muffleWarning = function() NULL)
```

This says -- signal a condtion, but insert a 'restart' where the condition was signaled from. Then you'd

```
withCallingHandlers({
    warning("curves ahead")
    2
}, warning = function(w) {
    ## what are you going to do with the warning?
    message("warning occurred: ", conditionMessage(w))
    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
})
```

Although `withCallingHandlers` is often used with warnings and `tryCatch` with errors, there is nothing to stop one from 'handling' an error or catching a warning if that is the appropriate action.

Comment: Wow, thanks man! Don't fully comprehend it yet and have to play it through with some of my own examples, but that looks *really* powerful! Awesome!

Comment: Martin, would you mind posting a little example that explains how `withRestarts()`, `simpleCondition()`, `signalCondition()` and `withCallingHandlers()` interact? I'm having trouble understanding args `cond`, `message` and `call` and your `expr` part of `withRestarts()` seems to be a bit more complex than those explained on the help page. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think I got the basic idea now. Consider this to be a great example: http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2012/10/error-handling-in-r/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=error-handling-in-r. Thanks again, really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You can recall the `forecast` within the `warning` section, something like this:

```
mod <- tryCatch(
  out <- forecast::auto.arima(x=y),
  error=function(e) {
    print(e)
  },
  warning=function(w) {
    print(w)
    out <- forecast::auto.arima(x=y)
    return(out)
  }
)
```

This will print a warning , but the result of forecast is stored in mod now.

```
<simpleWarning in kpss.test(x): p-value smaller than printed p-value>
> mod
Series: y 
ARIMA(4,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2     ar3      ar4      ma1
      0.6768  -0.2142  0.5025  -0.7125  -0.8277
s.e.  0.0749   0.0889  0.0874   0.0735   0.0485

sigma^2 estimated as 915556:  log likelihood=-780.33
AIC=1572.65   AICc=1573.62   BIC=1587.91
```

Comment: it is unefficient in case of heavy computation/processing. It solves the problem from a theoretical point of view but not at all from a practical one.

Comment: In any case I claim that the solution is efficient and the OP don't even ask for efficiency. Your comment is maybe theorically correct( I should test the solution in a big data context , by the way you should explain what do you mean by "heavy computation"), But in practice this comment is uneseful.

Comment: This is a bad solution since it doesn't reuse the result of `out`, but rather recomputes it on a warning.