# Alternative condition classes and handlers/restarts that can modify the original expression(s)

Tags: r, try-catch, handler, conditional-statements

Inspired by this awesome [post](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html#custom-signal-classes) I felt like playing around with condition handling a bit more.

I think I got it all figured out for `warning` and `error` (didn't check `message` in detail yet), but out of pure interest at this point I wondered

1. How the same paradigm could be used for alternative conditions (i.e. conditions simply inheriting from `condition`, not `message`, `warning` or `error`)
2. When, if at all, the use of such alternative conditions would make any sense in the first place (and/or when `signalCondition()` would actually be used)
3. How I can get a custom restart handler to "go back to the environment where the actual expression was evaluated" so it can "dynamically" work with/modify the original expression(s) (in frames further up the calling stack) in order to accomplish full flexibilty for condition handling

---

### Example

Default condition constructor:

```
condition <- function(subclass, message, call = sys.call(-1), ...) {
  structure(
    class = c(subclass, "condition"),
    list(message = message, call = call),
    ...
  )
}
```

Custom alternative condition constructor:

```
custom_condition <- function(subclass, message, call = sys.call(-1), ...) {
  cond <- condition(subclass, message, call = call, ...)
  message(cond)
}
```

Example function that issues two alternative conditions at some point:

```
foo <- function() {
    for (ii in 1:3) {
        message(paste0("Run #: ", ii))
        if (ii == 1) {
            custom_condition(subclass="conditionFooExample",
                message="I'm just an example condition")
        } else if (ii == 3) {
            custom_condition(subclass="conditionFooExample2",
                message="I'm just another example condition")
        }
        ii
    }
}
```

Running without any wrappers such as `tryCatch()`, `withCallingHandlers()`, `withRestarts()` or the like:

```
foo()
Run #: 1
I'm just an example condition
Run #: 2
Run #: 3
I'm just another example condition
```

As I see it, not really useful as I would have gotten the same result when simply issuing the messages directly via `message()` in `foo()` instead of creating customs conditions via `custom_condition()`.

This happens when wrapping it with `tryCatch()`:

```
tryCatch(
    foo(),
    conditionFooExample=function(cond) {
        cond
    },
    conditionFooExample2=function(cond) {
        cond
    }
)
Run #: 1
<conditionFooExample in foo(): I'm just an example condition>
```

As we see, the first condition leads to kind of a "graceful exit". As I see it, as is right now, not really useful either because it resembles the behavior of `warnings`.

So I thought if alternative conditions are to be useful at all, then this whole process would probably need to involve custom condition handlers (e.g. for logging purposes: "write something back to a DB and continue") and something similar to  `invokeRestart("muffleWarning")` (see `?condition` and look for `muffleWarning`) in order to "really continue" (as opposed to "gracefully exiting").

So I gues this would then look something like this (**PSEUDO CODE**)?

```
withRestarts(
    tryCatch(
        foo(),
        conditionFooExample=function(cond) {
            cond      ## possibly 'message(cond)' instead?
            ## Do something meaningful before invoking a restart
            invokeRestart("conditionFooExample")
        },
        conditionFooExample2=function(cond) {
            cond      ## possibly 'message(cond)' instead?
            ## Do something meaningful before invoking a restart
            invokeRestart("conditionFooExample2")
        }
    ),
    conditionFooExample=function() {
        ## (Maybe) do something more before continuing

        ## Then continue:
        invokeRestart("muffleCondition")
    },
    conditionFooExample2=function() {
        ## (Maybe) do something more before continuing

        ## Then continue:
        invokeRestart("muffleCondition")
    }
)
```

Of course, there is no such thing as `invokeRestart("muffleCondition")` and I'm also not sure if this "architecture" would make any sense.

**However, this is where question 3 came up: how do these restart handlers actually work, i.e. how do they get from their frame "one frame up" again?**

Last not least I asked myself what would happened if I used `signalCondition(cond)` instead of `message(cond)` in `custom_condition()`

```
custom_condition <- function(subclass, message, call = sys.call(-1), ...) {
  cond <- condition(subclass, message, call = call, ...)
  signalCondition(cond)
}

foo()
Run #: 1
Run #: 2
Run #: 3
```

So, this seems even more "unnecessary" that before as the function simply terminates.

This is how it would look with `tryCatch()`:

```
tryCatch(
    foo(),
    conditionFooExample=function(cond) {
        cond
    },
    conditionFooExample2=function(cond) {
        cond
    }
)

Run #: 1
<conditionFooExample in foo(): I'm just an example condition>
```

Well, the behavior itself does make sense, but I could have gotten the same result with an `error` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a hint about how restarts work from looking at the code to `warning`.

Here's a function providing two different restarts

```
f = function() {
    message("before")
    withRestarts({
        message("during")
        cond <- condition("restartable", "a restartable condition")
        signalCondition(cond)
    }, restart1 = function() {
        message("restarting 1")
    }, restart2 = function() {
        message("restarting 2")
    })
    message("after")
}
```

You can then choose to deal with your condition in different ways, e.g., not at all

```
> f()
before
during
after
```

catching the condition and terminating one way or another (your restarts are not available with tryCatch)

```
> tryCatch(f(), restartable=function(...) "did my best")
before
during
[1] "did my best"
> tryCatch(f(), restartable=function(cond) stop(conditionMessage(cond)))
before
during
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : a restartable condition
```

or using a calling handler to recover and try again

```
> withCallingHandlers(f(), restartable=function(...) invokeRestart("restart1"))
before
during
restarting 1
after
> withCallingHandlers(f(), restartable=function(...) invokeRestart("restart2"))
before
during
restarting 2
after
```

Not really sure if this helps or not; it would be really super if these facilities were used more extensively, especially signalling errors with subclasses.

Comment: Cool beans, thanks man! That definitely shed some light on some of my questions. I totally agree that these capabilities should be used more extensively! One question remains, though: what would/should/can I tell these restart handlers to actually do? In my mind there's this idea of "if the original expression didn't work, try altering it", e.g. by changing some values and re-evaluating it. Or continuing a `for` loop at/after the position that a cond. occurred. So I'm thinking they must be able to access stuff from a state before the cond. occured. Or is that asked too much of them? ;-)

Comment: Or do I simply put some "static" alternative expression/code in them? E.g. "if the original expression didn't work, use some registered default values and try that". *Static* in the sense that the expression in the restart handler doesn't really have anything to do with what was called as `expr` in `tryCatch()`, `withCallingHandlers()` etc.

Comment: Maybe this makes it a bit clearer what I actually mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440226/advanced-error-handling-systematically-try-a-range-of-handlers. E.g. when `expr <- substitute(foo(x=x, y=y))`, you could try to systematically change the value of `x` in case something you tried failed: `expr$x <- <some-alternative-value>`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I got the "how to make handlers 'dynamical'" figured out now.

The trick is to use `sys.frame()` if you want to "dynamically" change values in the frame where the original expression (argument `expr`) of `withCallingHandlers()` is evaluated.

To see what's going on, you can call `sys.calls()` and `sys.call()` inside your handler.

Note that it is **not** necessary to actually re-evaluate the original expression inside the handler after you made your changes! `withCallingHandlers()` takes care of that automatically (i.e. we could have omitted `value <- eval(sys.call(-pos))` in the example below).

---

### Example

Default condition constructor:

```
condition <- function(subclass, message, call=sys.call(-1), ...) {
  structure(
    class=c(subclass, "condition"),
    list(message=message, call=call),
    ...
  )
}
```

Custom condition signaler:

```
custom_triggerCondition <- function(subclass, message, call=sys.call(-1), ...) {
  cond <- condition(subclass, message, call=call, ...)
  signalCondition(cond)
}
```

Example function in which custom signaler is used:

```
myLog <- function(x) {
    if (is.numeric(x) && x == 5) {
        custom_triggerCondition(subclass="MyTriggerCondition", 
            message="This is an example alternative condition"
        )
    }
    log(x)
}
myLog(2)
[1] 0.6931472
myLog(5)
[1] 1.609438
```

Note how `MyTriggerCondition` differs from a `message`: unless we provide a handler, nothing happens and/or is signaled.

Let's see how things look when the conditions for signaling `MyTriggerCondition` are **not** met:

```
## No condition signaled //
res <- withCallingHandlers(
    {
        myLog(x=2)
    },
    ## Handler for message condition class 'MyTriggerCondition' // 
    MyTriggerCondition=function(cond) {
        ## Omitted for the sake of compactness. 
        ## See next call to 'withCallingHandlers()' for actual code
        return(NULL)
    }
)
```

This gives us:

```
res
[1] 0.6931472
```

Let's see how things look when the conditions for signaling `MyTriggerCondition` **are** met:

```
## Condition 'MyTriggerCondition' signaled //
res <- withCallingHandlers(
    {
        myLog(x=5)
    },
    ## Handler for message condition class 'MyTriggerCondition' // 
    MyTriggerCondition=function(cond) {
        message("handler> System calls:")
        syscalls <- sys.calls()
        print(syscalls)
        message("-------------------------------------------------------------")
        message("handler> This is what happened:")
        message(conditionMessage(cond))
        message("handler> Condition class:")
        print(class(cond))
        message("handler> Now I'm handling the condition by changing 'x' to 10:")
        pos <- length(syscalls) - 2
        message(c(
                paste0("handler> Need to go back '", pos, "'\n"),
                "handler> frames for the desired system call:")
        )
        message(paste0("handler> Getting system call [-", pos, "]:"))
        syscall <- sys.call(-pos)
        print(syscall)
        message(paste0("handler> Evaluating system call [-", pos, "]:"))
        value <- eval(sys.call(-pos))
        message("handler> Evaluation result:")
        print(value)
        message(paste0("handler> Getting system frame [-", pos, "]:"))
        sysframe <- sys.frame(-pos)
        print(sysframe)
        message(paste0("handler> Listing content of system frame [-", pos, "]:"))
        print(ls(sysframe))
        message(paste0("handler> Getting old value of 'x' in system frame [-", pos, "]:"))
        print(sysframe$x)
        message(paste0("handler> Overwriting content of system frame [-", pos, "]:"))
        message("handler> 'x' is set to 10")
        sysframe$x <- 10
        message(paste0("handler> Inspect overwriting result in system frame [-", pos, "]:"))
        print(sysframe$x)
        message(paste0("handler> Re-evaluating system call [-", pos, "] (locally):"))
        value <- eval(sys.call(-pos))
        message("handler> Re-evaluation result (locally):")
        print(value)
        message(c(
            "handler> IMPORTANT:\n",
            "handler> Note how the expression evaluated is still\n",
            paste0("handler> myLog(x=5): ", value, "when re-evaluated 'locally'\n"),
            "handler> inside the handler function.\n",
            "handler> But also note that the **actual** return value\n",
            "handler> of the handler or 'withCallingHandlers()'\n",
            "handler> will be myLog(x=10): 2.302585 as the handler\n",
            "handler> changed the value of 'x'!"
            )
        )
        return(value)
    }
)
```

Let's run this:

```
handler> System calls:
[[1]]
withCallingHandlers({
    myLog(x = 5)
}, MyTriggerCondition = function(cond) {
    message("handler> System calls:")
    syscalls <- sys.calls()
    print(syscalls)
    message("-------------------------------------------------------------")
    message("handler> This is what happened:")
    message(conditionMessage(cond))
    message("handler> Condition class:")
    print(class(cond))
    message("handler> Now I'm handling the condition by changing 'x' to 10:")
    pos <- length(syscalls) - 2
    message(c(paste0("handler> Need to go back '", pos, "'\n"), 
        "handler> frames for the desired system call:"))
    message(paste0("handler> Getting system call [-", pos, "]:"))
    syscall <- sys.call(-pos)
    print(syscall)
    message(paste0("handler> Evaluating system call [-", pos, 
        "]:"))
    value <- eval(sys.call(-pos))
    message("handler> Evaluation result:")
    print(value)
    message(paste0("handler> Getting system frame [-", pos, "]:"))
    sysframe <- sys.frame(-pos)
    print(sysframe)
    message(paste0("handler> Listing content of system frame [-", 
        pos, "]:"))
    print(ls(sysframe))
    message(paste0("handler> Getting old value of 'x' in system frame [-", 
        pos, "]:"))
    print(sysframe$x)
    message(paste0("handler> Overwriting content of system frame [-", 
        pos, "]:"))
    message("handler> 'x' is set to 10")
    sysframe$x <- 10
    message(paste0("handler> Inspect overwriting result in system frame [-", 
        pos, "]:"))
    print(sysframe$x)
    message(paste0("handler> Re-evaluating system call [-", pos, 
        "] (locally):"))
    value <- eval(sys.call(-pos))
    message("handler> Re-evaluation result (locally):")
    print(value)
    message(c("handler> IMPORTANT:\n", "handler> Note how the expression evaluated is still\n", 
        paste0("handler> myLog(x=5): ", value, "when re-evaluated 'locally'\n"), 
        "handler> inside the handler function.\n", "handler> But also note that the **actual** return value\n", 
        "handler> of the handler or 'withCallingHandlers()'\n", 
        "handler> will be myLog(x=10): 2.302585 as the handler\n", 
        "handler> changed the value of 'x'!"))
    return(value)
})

[[2]]
myLog(x = 5)

[[3]]
custom_triggerCondition(subclass = "MyTriggerCondition", message = "This is an example alternative condition")

[[4]]
signalCondition(cond)

[[5]]
(function (cond) 
{
    message("handler> System calls:")
    syscalls <- sys.calls()
    print(syscalls)
    message("-------------------------------------------------------------")
    message("handler> This is what happened:")
    message(conditionMessage(cond))
    message("handler> Condition class:")
    print(class(cond))
    message("handler> Now I'm handling the condition by changing 'x' to 10:")
    pos <- length(syscalls) - 2
    message(c(paste0("handler> Need to go back '", pos, "'\n"), 
        "handler> frames for the desired system call:"))
    message(paste0("handler> Getting system call [-", pos, "]:"))
    syscall <- sys.call(-pos)
    print(syscall)
    message(paste0("handler> Evaluating system call [-", pos, 
        "]:"))
    value <- eval(sys.call(-pos))
    message("handler> Evaluation result:")
    print(value)
    message(paste0("handler> Getting system frame [-", pos, "]:"))
    sysframe <- sys.frame(-pos)
    print(sysframe)
    message(paste0("handler> Listing content of system frame [-", 
        pos, "]:"))
    print(ls(sysframe))
    message(paste0("handler> Getting old value of 'x' in system frame [-", 
        pos, "]:"))
    print(sysframe$x)
    message(paste0("handler> Overwriting content of system frame [-", 
        pos, "]:"))
    message("handler> 'x' is set to 10")
    sysframe$x <- 10
    message(paste0("handler> Inspect overwriting result in system frame [-", 
        pos, "]:"))
    print(sysframe$x)
    message(paste0("handler> Re-evaluating system call [-", pos, 
        "] (locally):"))
    value <- eval(sys.call(-pos))
    message("handler> Re-evaluation result (locally):")
    print(value)
    message(c("handler> IMPORTANT:\n", "handler> Note how the expression evaluated is still\n", 
        paste0("handler> myLog(x=5): ", value, "when re-evaluated 'locally'\n"), 
        "handler> inside the handler function.\n", "handler> But also note that the **actual** return value\n", 
        "handler> of the handler or 'withCallingHandlers()'\n", 
        "handler> will be myLog(x=10): 2.302585 as the handler\n", 
        "handler> changed the value of 'x'!"))
    return(value)
})(list(message = "This is an example alternative condition", 
    call = myLog(x = 5)))

-------------------------------------------------------------
handler> This is what happened:
This is an example alternative condition
handler> Condition class:
[1] "MyTriggerCondition" "condition"         
handler> Now I'm handling the condition by changing 'x' to 10:
handler> Need to go back '3'
handler> frames for the desired system call:
handler> Getting system call [-3]:
myLog(x = 5)
handler> Evaluating system call [-3]:
handler> Evaluation result:
[1] 1.609438
handler> Getting system frame [-3]:
<environment: 0x000000001eb17c98>
handler> Listing content of system frame [-3]:
[1] "x"
handler> Getting old value of 'x' in system frame [-3]:
[1] 5
handler> Overwriting content of system frame [-3]:
handler> 'x' is set to 10
handler> Inspect overwriting result in system frame [-3]:
[1] 10
handler> Re-evaluating system call [-3] (locally):
handler> Re-evaluation result (locally):
[1] 1.609438
handler> IMPORTANT:
handler> Note how the expression evaluated is still
handler> myLog(x=5): 1.6094379124341when re-evaluated 'locally'
handler> inside the handler function.
handler> But also note that the **actual** return value
handler> of the handler or 'withCallingHandlers()'
handler> will be myLog(x=10): 2.302585 as the handler
handler> changed the value of 'x'!
```

The value of `res` now is:

```
res
[1] 2.302585
```