# Catch specific warning and ignore others

Tags: r, try-catch

I'm debugging some code which gives several warnings, but I'm trying to stop the code when I receive a specific warning so I can look at the environment.

For example:

```
myfun <- function(){
  warning("The wrong warning")
  warning("The right warning")
  print("The end of the function")
}

tryCatch(myfun(),
         warning = function(w){
           if(grepl("right", w$message)){
             stop("I have you now")
           } else {
             message(w$message)
           }
         })
```

What I'd like to happen is for the function to stop at "The right warning", but the catch stops as soon as it receives its first warning. How can I skip over warnings that aren't of interest and stop on the ones that interest me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `withCallingHandlers` is what you want: [Disregarding simple warnings/errors in tryCatch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295004/disregarding-simple-warnings-errors-in-trycatch?rq=1)

```
withCallingHandlers(myfun(),
   warning = function(w){
     if(grepl("right", w$message)){
       stop("I have you now")
     } else {
       message(w$message)
     }
   })
```

Comment: That's dead on it. I'm going to mark my question as duplicate.