# Ignoring specific warnings but not others in R

Tags: r, try-catch, warnings

This question is similar, but different from [Disregarding simple warnings/errors in tryCatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295004/disregarding-simple-warnings-errors-in-trycatch).  I am reading an Excel file from an external source over which I have no control.  I frequently encounter one of more warnings when it's reading scientific notation.  Since the read_excel file handles these well, I'd like to ignore those warnings but display any others that might be generated.  Here is some data in a CSV format.

```
V1,V2,V3,V4    
A,0,0,Include    
B,0,0,Include     
C,0,-2.0484947071963688E-11,Include    
D,0,-9.1299973,Include    
E,1.8488805068272995E-05,0,Include    
F,0.003399333,0,Include    
G,-9.902539136998455E-05,0,Include    
H,-0.000442444,0,Include    
I,-4.561459166153803E-05,0,Include    
J,-0.00095274,0,Include
```

Let's say those 4 columns and 10 rows are in an Excel file called 'example.xlsx'.  The following code will generate 4 warnings to the effect that it is "Coercing text to numeric" which is related to rows C, E, G, and I being in scientific notation.

```
readxl::read_excel("example.xlsx", .name_repair = "unique",
               col_types = c("guess",  
                             rep("numeric", 2),
                             "guess"))
```

The `length(warnings()` will be 4.  I would like to suppress warnings of this type and pass through other warnings (and errors).  If the warnings are only of this type ("Coercing text to numeric") then I want to return the results of the function because it converts those values fine.

I'm stuck on tryCatch (and lost on withCallingHandlers).  The warning_message created by the tryCatch function seems to only catch the first warning and not all of them.  Also, when there are only the warning I want to ignore, can I return the results of the read_excel function (without having to call the function a second time?

Here is a concept of what I'd like to accomplish.  First, here's a function which would help if I could access the warnings() function within tryCatch.

```
ignoreWarnings <- function(w){    
  for(i in names(w)){    
    if(regexpr("Coercing text to numeric", i) == -1) return(FALSE)   
  }    
  return(TRUE)    
}
```

Then the tryCatch might look like this:

```
tryCatch(out <- readxl::read_excel("example.xlsx", .name_repair =
 "unique",
                                    col_types = c("guess",  
                                                  rep("numeric", 2),
                                                  "guess")),
                 error = function(error_message){
                   message(error_message)
                   return(NA)
                 },
                 warning = function(warning_message){
                   if(ignoreWarnings(warning_message)){
                     return(out)
                   } else {
                     message(warning_message)
                     return(NA)  
                   }

                 }
          )
```

In the case where ignoreWarnings is TRUE, we return `out` which is the result of the read_excel function as if there were no errors or warnings.  If FALSE, we pass through the warnings and return NA.

I realize the `warning_message` is different from warnings().  I don't seem to be able to access warnings() in tryCatch.  It would be nice to avoid having to call the read_excel twice in the case there are only warnings to be ignored.