# How to trace where the Error occurs when executing a `mapply()`?

Tags: r

I have a data.table of 600,000 rows and execute the following command on it:

```
ranges <- mapply(function(mi, ma) {seq(from=mi, to=ma, by="days")}, mi=Moves$Start, ma=Moves$End)
```

I get the following error message after a while:

```
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

I have tested my code with a smaller dataset and that seems to be working fine. This leads me to think that the error message is the result of the values in the dataset. Can anybody recommend an efficient way to trace the problem row(s) in the data.table? Needless to say, manually checking 600k rows is a bit too much.

Your suggestions for finding the problem rows in the data.table are appreciated!

Comment: you can start with replacing `seq(from=mi, to=ma, by="days")` with `cat(mi,ma,"\n")` to see when does it fail

Comment: also are you sure it's `by="days"` and not `by=days` where days is a variable?

Comment: @geektrader I'm pretty sure the `by` argument in `seq.Date` accepts "days"

Comment: @joran but error says `seq.int`

Comment: I save the warnings and errors from each step separately and look through them afterwards.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4948361/210673

Comment: @geektrader Good point, yes.

Comment: @geektrader: `by="days"` is correct and `by=days` results in an instant error

Comment: @geektrader but that is an internal function. I can reproduce the error when the `from` is after the `to`; you can't go back in time by using positive time steps, only negative ones. See my answer for a reproducible call that results in the error Jochem is seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview

[`seq.Date()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.Date.html)'s error message is trying to tell you that a date in `Moves$End` (i.e. June 23, 2017) occurs **before** `Moves$Start` (i.e. April 17, 2017). Because `seq.Date()` assumes all dates in `from` occur before the dates in `to`, the error stops the function from proceeding.

To identify where this occurs, use [`which()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.html) to identify which dates in `Moves$End` are less than `Moves$Start`. From there, update those dates so that they occur **after** `Moves$Start`.

```
# load necessary data
Moves <- data.frame( Start = as.Date( x = c("2017-04-17", "2018-03-01", "2019-04-01") )
                     , End = as.Date( x = c("2017-06-23", "2018-02-14", "2018-04-24") )
                     , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

# try to create a sequence of dates
date.ranges <-
  mapply( FUN = function( mi, ma )
  seq.Date( from = mi
            , to = ma
            , by = "day" )
  , Moves$Start
  , Moves$End
  , SIMPLIFY = FALSE )

# identify the instance
# where the End date occurs
# before the Start date
wrong.end.date <-
  which( Moves$End < Moves$Start )

# view results
wrong.end.date
# [1] 2 3

# correct those End Dates
# so that they occur 
# after the Start date
Moves$End[ wrong.end.date ] <-
  as.Date( x = c("2019-02-14", "2019-04-24") )

# rerun the mapply() function
date.ranges <-
  mapply( FUN = function( mi, ma )
    seq.Date( from = mi
              , to = ma
              , by = "day" )
    , Moves$Start
    , Moves$End
    , SIMPLIFY = FALSE )

# end of script #
```

Answer (score 3):

The obvious solution is to turn the anonymous function into a first class, fully named function, and then you can debug the function. Or turn on the recover option and then you can step into the evaluation frames for the current stack and see the state of the variables at the point the error was raised.

```
myFun <- function(mi, ma) {
  seq(from=mi, to=ma, by="days")
}
```

gets you a named function, which you can debug via

```
debug(myFun)
```

or

```
debugonce(myFun)
```

To turn on error recovery do

```
op <- options(error = recover)
```

(you can rest that then with: `options(op)` or `options(error = stop)`

In this case I suspect that `mi` is greater than `ma`:

```
> myFun(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()-1)
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

so you could alter `myFun` to see if that is the case:

```
myFun <- function(mi, ma) {
  if(mi > ma)
    stop("`mi` is > than `ma`")
  seq(from=mi, to=ma, by="days")
}
```

That way you get a more informative error message.

If that fails I'd use `options(error = recover)` and then drop into the evaluation call corresponding to the function and see what the values of `mi` and `ma` are.