# Using tryCatch() to catch a bootstrap loop

Tags: r, loops, try-catch, statistics-bootstrap

I have insufficient knolwedge on the use of `tryCatch()` but have found it hard to find a good solution in the ongoing discussions.

I have a self-programmed function which returns an object. It is actually a list object, but for simplicity assume it is a scalar. I am using a `for()` loop to bootstrap this function. My loop is of the following form:

```
boot<-1000
for(i in 1:boot){
  bootstrap_data<-data[sample(nrow(data),nrow(data),replace=T),]
  out[i]<-myfunction(bootstrap_data,X,...)
}
```

`myfunction()` sometimes returns an error message, because it uses `lm()` to fit a model on a subset of the data and then predict new data from a different subset. Then it can happen that for certain factors some levels by chance do not appear in the data used to fit, but they do appear in the prediction subset. This does happen very rarely (say, roughly every 15,000 iterations), but it does happen (I need to bootstrap `myfunction()` a lot of times).

I want to use `tryCatch()` or a similar function to catch my bootstrap loop. Furthermore, I would like to define an index that counts how often across the loops `tryCatch()` had to catch the function. Finally, I would like to have a constant number `boot` regardless of the number of times the error occured.

R returns the following message:

```
    Error in model.frame.default(Terms,newdata,na.action=na.action,
xlev=object$xlevels) : factor X has new levels 2
```

`X` is a user specified predictor in `lm()`. I am not sure what 2 stands for, I guess the number of new levels(?).

Comment: When I need to do this, I catch the warnings and errors in a list and process afterwards.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4948361/210673.  If you need to do this many times, it might be too slow for you, but might help in giving you some helpful ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the function that sometimes throws an error in a "try" usually works for me.

```
boot<-1000
for(i in 1:boot){
  bootstrap_data<-data[sample(nrow(data),nrow(data),replace=T),]
  out[i] = NA  #
  try({      
    out[i]<-myfunction(bootstrap_data,X,...)
  }, silent=T)
}
```

If you want to count the number of errors thrown you can sum up the NA's in out.

```
sum(is.na(out))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that sometimes fails

```
f <- function() {
    r <- rnorm(1)
    if (r > 1)
        stop("oops")
    r
}
```

we allocate a result vector and set up a counter to update the ith element

```
out <- numeric(100)
i <- 0
```

then repeatedly try to call the function. If there's an error, we don't increment i or record the result, but instead go directly to the next iteration

```
while (i < length(out)) {
    tryCatch({
        out[[i + 1]] <- f()
        i <- i + 1
    }, error=function(...) NULL)
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to use try instead of tryCatch in your example?

Comment: Your answer is very similar to kith's. Thanks.

Comment: @tomka ok removed the try illustration you requested earlier.