# implementing tryCatch R

Tags: r, error-handling

Trying to use `tryCatch`. What I want is to run through a list of urls that I have stored in `page1URLs` and if there is a problem with one of them (using `readHTMLTable()` )I want a record of which ones and then I want the code to go on to the next url without crashing.

I think I don't have the right idea here at all. Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Here is the beginning of the code:

```
baddy <- rep(NA,10,000)
badURLs <- function(url) { baddy=c(baddy,url) }

writeURLsToCsvExtrema(38.361042, 35.465144, 141.410522, 139.564819)

writeURLsToCsvExtrema <- function(maxlat, minlat, maxlong, minlong) {

urlsFuku <- page1URLs
allFuku <- data.frame() # need to initialize it with column names

for (url in urlsFuku) {

    tryCatch(temp.tables=readHTMLTable(url), finally=badURLs(url))

    temp.df <- temp.tables[[3]]
    lastrow <- nrow(temp.df)
    temp.df <- temp.df[-c(lastrow-1,lastrow),] 

}
```

Comment: Here's what I do: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4948361/210673; also see the linked questions there.

Answer (score 2):

One general approach is to write a function that fully processes one URL, returning either the computed value or NULL to indicate failure

```
FUN = function(url) {
    tryCatch({
        xx <- readHTMLTable(url)  ## will sometimes fail, invoking 'error' below
        ## more calculations
        xx  ## final value
    }, error=function(err) {
        ## what to do on error? could return conditionMessage(err) or other...
        NULL
    })
}
```

and then use this, e.g., with a named vector

```
urls <- c("http://cran.r-project.org", "http://stackoverflow.com", 
          "http://foo.bar")
names(urls) <- urls           # add names to urls, so 'result' elements are named
result <- lapply(urls, FUN)
```

These guys failed (returned NULL)

```
> names(result)[sapply(result, is.null)]
[1] "http://foo.bar"
```

And these are the results for further processing

```
final <- Filter(Negate(is.null), result)
```

Comment: are saying to define FUN like this:

FUN = function(url) {
    tryCatch({
 temp.tables=readHTMLTable(url) 
        #do some other stuff
    }, error=function(err) {
       
        badURLS=c(badURLS,url) #this may be unnecessary according to what you suggested.
         NULL
    })

and then run it like this:

result <- lapply(urlsFuku, FUN)

}

Comment: just use `error=function(err) { NULL }`; result from lapply will be a named list, names of list elements with value NULL will be failed urls.

Comment: I am not clear about what this is for.   names(urls) <- urls. Do I need this?

Comment: compare `lapply(c(1, 2), function(x) x)` with `lapply(c(a=1, b=2), function(x) x)`. In the second case, the argument to lapply has names, and the result has names. So you know which result is associated with which original element.