# How can I run a simulation with the "try" function in R and keep only the results that worked

Tags: r, subset

I am using the 'try' function to create some subsets but I cannot manage to keep only the results taht worked with the 'try' function. Below is the line of code I have.

```
list_shp_Deforested_2000_Africa <- lapply(list_shp_FC_Africa, function(x){try(x[x$D_90_00!=100,],)})
```

Does somebody know the function which will allow me to keep only the result that worked? Thanks for your help?

Comment: Here's how I do this. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4948361/210673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask about the `try` function, you should read `help(try)` first. The last line in the examples does what you are interested in (where you should substitute `list_shp_Deforested_2000_Africa` for `res`).

```
unlist(res[sapply(res, function(x) !inherits(x, "try-error"))])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `Filter` the list to not include those that inherit "try-error"

```
Filter(function(x) !inherits(x, "try-error"), list_shp_Deforested_2000_Africa)
```

Or, if you used `tryCatch` and return `NULL` if there is an error, it might be cleaner

```
L <- lapply(1:10, function(x) tryCatch(if(runif(1) > 0.5) stop() else 42, error=function(e) NULL))
Filter(length, L)
```