# Using "if" to deal with an error in optim() R cran

Tags: r, optimization

i'm using R, the "optim" code to obtain maxims of a function. I'm performing the optimization 100 times with equally number random samples but in cases there's one sample for you can't obtain the result and i get this error code:

> Error en optim(theta, objective, yt = rbind(yt), hessian = TRUE) :
>     non-finite finite-difference value [3]

since is an iterative process when this happens the code stop and don't save the previous results

is there any way to indicate that if i get this error message the routine continues anyway?

i was thinking using a "for" line, let's say

```
if(length(fit)!=6){fit <-c(0,0,0)}
```

or

```
if(fit=="NA"){fit$par <-c(0,0,0)}
```

here fit is the name i gave to the optim line.

So that way instead of getting the error i would assign a vector of zeros and the routine can goes on but it didn't work. Any ideas or comments?

Comment: Here's what I do. There are several other similar questions linked there as well. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4948361/210673

Comment: Beware of `fit == "NA"`. For instance, `NA == "NA"`. Consider `is.na()`