# save warnings/errors from function without showing on screen

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I found this very helpful factory to convert any function into  a function that capture its values, errors, and warnings ([How do I save warnings and errors as output from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948361/how-do-i-save-warnings-and-errors-as-output-from-a-function/4952908#4952908)):

```
factory <- function(fun)
function(...) {
    warn <- err <- NULL
    res <- withCallingHandlers(
        tryCatch(fun(...), error=function(e) {
            err <<- conditionMessage(e)
            NULL
        }), warning=function(w) {
            warn <<- append(warn, conditionMessage(w))
            invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
        })
    list(res, warn=warn, err=err)
}
```

My problem is that errors/warnings are also shown on screen (on top of being captured by the factory). How can I change it so that errors/warnings do not show on screen?
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what  you mean? `f  = factory(stop("oops")); res = f()` returns without any output to the screen.

Comment: You are right Martin... I was not clear. The function I am using with factory downloads streaming data from a financial website. It outputs several messages to screen via cat. Some of these messages end up being errors and can block the function. The function has a verbose parameter which can block all cat messages.

Comment: If I set verbose=T, factory captures correctly all warning/errors but also shows all cats on screen. If I set verbose=F, factory misses important warnings coming via cat (even when blocking the function) and does not show cats on screen. The function is quite complex and I cannot change it. I would rather modify slightly factory so that cat messages are captured as warning (as it already happens) but are not shown on screen.

Comment: You can use `capture.output()` to capture `cat()` output, but really the function that you are calling should be modified to use stop / warning / message as appropriate.

Comment: how would I use capture.output()? I tried factory(capture.output(fun))(...) but this give an error as output ( "could not find function \"fun\""). I also tried capture.output(factory(fun)(...)) and this return a long text output without the output intended. Unfortunately I cannot change the function. It is quite complex for my competence and there is no way to know what messages the financial site will actually send. I get a mixture of intended output and many other less important messages...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your options so that error messages aren't shown. In the body of the function you can call the following code:

```
options(show.error.messages= FALSE)
```

Don't forget to turn it into `TRUE` before leaving, it's always useful to see error messages.