# Suppress warnings using tryCatch in R

Tags: r, try-catch, suppress-warnings

## What I'm trying to do

Write a `tryCatch` that will handle an error value but will ignore a warning. As an example

```
foo <- function(x) {
  if (x == 1) {
    warning('Warning')
  } else if (x == 0) {
    stop('Error')
  }
  return(1)
}

bar <- function(x){
  tryCatch(
    expr    = foo(x),
    error   = identity,
    warning = function(w) invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
  )
}
```

So `foo` warns you if you pass a 0, and errors if you pass a 1. The intent of `bar` is that you get an error if you pass a 0, but it suppresses the warning generated by `bar` if you pass a 1. The `invokeRestart("muffleWarning")` command comes from the definition of `suppressWarnings`. It does not work in the construction I have here and I do not know why. (Ironically it generates an error, so trying that successfully escalated a warning I didn't want into an error that I can't interpret.)

## The Dumb Answer (TM) I don't want to use and why

This definition of `bar` will work

```
bar <- function(x){
  tryCatch(
    expr    = foo(x),
    error   = SomeFunctionThatDoesNotMatter,
    warning = function(w){suppressWarnings(foo(x))}
  )
}
```

`bar` does exactly what I want it to, but it does it in a potentially terrible way. Imagine that instead of `expr = foo(x)` as I have here, that I have `expr = lapply(X=1:50, ...)` and that the `FUN` takes an hour to run. If `X[50]` generates the only warning then my run time has double from 50 hours to 100 hours (yuck).

## The Questions

1. Why does `invokeRestart("muffleWarning")` not work in my example above?
2. When using `tryCatch`, what function should be assigned to `warning` in order to allow the code to simply keep running and suppress the warnings that are generated?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Try `warning = function(w) { }`

Comment: I need `bar` to still return the value of `foo(x)`

Comment: Use `withCallingHandlers()`, illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948361/how-do-i-save-warnings-and-errors-as-output-from-a-function/4952908#4952908)

Comment: @MartinMorgan: that works. There seems to be a little overhead (which is  almost certainly unavoidable). Do you want to "answer" the question? Also, any idea why `invokeRestart("muffleWarning")` works inside `withCallingHandlers()`, but not inside `tryCatch`?

Comment: The answer to use `withCallingHandlers()` has been given before, so no value 'answering' again. See ?withCallingHandlers for the difference with tryCatch. The former remembers the call stack down to the point where the condition was signaled, so execution can resume where it left off. tryCatch unwinds the call stack to the point where tryCatch was established, so execution can't resume. You can use an error handler with withCallingHandlers, or a warning handler with tryCatch, but neither use makes sense: an error means that the code can't continue, and a warning doesn't mean you have to stop.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem after following nrussell's intuition. The solution is to replace the generic

```
tryCatch({
  some_fn()
}, warning = function(w) {
  print(paste('warning:', w))
}, error = function(e) {
  print(paste('error:', e))
})
```

with

```
tryCatch({
  some_fn()
}, error = function(e) {
  print(paste('error:', e))
})
```

This format/syntax has worked for me. You could easily enclose it in a function like you need to