# How to capture particular warning message and execute call

Tags: r, try-catch, warnings

Lately when I run my code that uses coxph in the survival package 
`coxph(frml,data = data)`, I am now getting warning messages of the following type

> 1: In model.matrix.default(Terms, mf, contrasts = contrast.arg) :
>    partial argument match of 'contrasts' to 'contrasts.arg'
>
> > 2: In seq.default(along = temp) :
> >      partial argument match of 'along' to 'along.with'"

I'm not exactly sure why all of a sudden these partial argument match warnings started popping up, but I don't think they effect me.

However, when I get the following warning message, I want `coxph(frml,data = data) = NA`

> 3: In fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
>     Loglik converged before variable  2 ; beta may be infinite.
>
> > 6: In coxph(frml, data = data) :
> >       X matrix deemed to be singular; variable 1 3 4

I used tryCatch when I wasn't getting the partial argument match warning using this code where if the nested tryCatch got either a warning or error message it would return NA

`coxphfit = tryCatch(tryCatch(coxph(frml,data = data), error=function(w) return(NA)), warning=function(w) return(NA))`

However, now that I am getting the partial argument match warnings, I need to only return an NA if there is an error or if I get the above warning messages 3 and 4 . Any idea about how to capture these particular warning messages and return an NA in those instances?

Comment: Have a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29465795/1655567).

Answer (score 2):

It's actually interesting question, if you are looking for quick and dirty way of capturing warnings you could simply do:

```
   withCallingHandlers({
    warning("hello")
    1 + 2
}, warning = function(w) {
    w ->> w 
}) -> res
```

In this example the object **`w`** created in parent environment would be:

```
>> w
<simpleWarning in withCallingHandlers({    warning("hello")    1 + 2}, warning = function(w) {    w <<- w}): hello>
```

You could then interrogate it:

```
grepl(x = w$message, pattern = "hello")
# [1] TRUE
```

as

```
>> w$message
# [1] "hello"
```

Object `res` would contain your desired results:

```
>> res
[1] 3
```

It's not the super tidy way but I reckon you could always reference object **`w`** and check if the warning message has the phrase you are interested in.