# Converting a function into a function with error handling in a specific case

Tags: r, function, error-handling

I would like to use function for the accepted answer from this question:

[How do I save warnings and errors as output from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948361/how-do-i-save-warnings-and-errors-as-output-from-a-function)

```
factory <- function(fun)
    function(...) {
        warn <- err <- NULL
        res <- withCallingHandlers(
            tryCatch(fun(...), error=function(e) {
                err <<- conditionMessage(e)
                NULL
            }), warning=function(w) {
                warn <<- append(warn, conditionMessage(w))
                invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
            })
        list(res, warn=warn, err=err)
    }
```

for use with the following function:

```
rbindlistfun <- function(df1, df2) {
x <- rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)
return (x)
}
```

The answer to the OP gives the following example:

```
test <- function(i)
    switch(i, "1"=stop("oops"), "2"={ warning("hmm"); i }, i)
res <- lapply(1:3, factory(test))
```

But I do not completely understand how this relates to my function. How do I use the factory function with my example?

Comment: I think there is an error in your `factory()` function. Do you really need that `function(...)` on the second line?

Comment: @AshwinMalshe I did not write the code, but I think it should be fine (I got it from another post, but accidentally linked it to the wrong post, it has the right link now).