# TryCatch warning inside 2 lapply

Tags: r, try-catch, lapply

I've got the following code:

```
fit.list <- lapply(sample.names, function(sample.name) {
    lapply(f1(target), function(seq.name) {
        f2(arguments)
    })
})
```

f2 is returning sometimes:

```
warning("Warning message")
return(NULL)
```

How can I catch the warning message inside the second lapply? I'm a newbie to R, excuse me.

EDITED:

Could be one of these workarounds?

1

```
tryCatch({
        fit.list <- lapply(sample.names, function(sample.name) {
            print(sample.name);
            lapply(f1(target), function(seq.name) {
                f2(arguments)
            })
        })
    }, 
    warning=function(e) {
            message(paste("Warning caused by sample:", sample))
            return(NULL)
        })
```

2

```
fit.list <- lapply(sample.names, function(sample.name) {
    
    tryCatch({
        lapply(f1(target), function(seq.name) {
            f2(arguments)
        })
    }, 
    warning=function(e) {
            message(paste("Warning caused by sample:", sample))
            return(NULL)
        })
})
```

3

```
fit.list <- lapply(sample.names, function(sample.name) {

    lapply(f1(target), function(seq.name) {
    
        tryCatch({
            f2(arguments)
        }, 
        warning=function(e) {
            message(paste("Warning caused by sample:", sample))
            return(NULL)
        })  
    })
})
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to stop warning from displaying you can use `suppressWarnings()`.

Comment: Hello Ronak, no I want to catch the warning and extract some info. For example what 'arguments' values caused the warning. Thanks!

Comment: Can you make this question reproducible and show expected output for it?

Comment: Hello again ronak, I'm afraid I can not. This piece of code is part of the user guide for an external R library (exomeCopy https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/exomeCopy/inst/doc/exomeCopy.pdf) and needs several external input resources that I can't provide.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952908/680068, see Martin's `factory` function.

Comment: First off, I'd check your argument names.  You use `sample.name` as an argument in your first anonymous function but don't use it in its body.  Similarly, `seq.name` in the second anonymous function.  That strikes me as odd.  Also, you haven't defined `target` or `arguments` in your code fragment.  As @Ronak said, without a MWE, our options to help are limited.

Comment: I am going to test first options(warn=2) (or 1) before this workaround, only for simplicity. Thank you!.