# capturing convergence message from lme4 package in R

Tags: r, function, regression, lme4

I was wondering if there is a way to write a logical test (`TRUE/FALSE`) to show whether a model from `lme4` package has converged or not?

An example is shown below, I want to capture if any model comes with the convergence warning (i.e., `Model failed to converge`) message?

```
library(lme4)

dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/nc.csv')

m <- lmer(math ~ ses*sector + (ses | sch.id), data = dat)

Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00279 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tryCatch`, using `withCallingHandlers` taking inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952908/3962914) post.

```
dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/nc.csv')

m <- tryCatch({
          withCallingHandlers({
            error <- FALSE
            list(model = lmer(math ~ ses*sector + (ses | sch.id), data = dat),
                 error = error)
          },warning = function(w) {
              if(grepl('failed to converge', w$message)) error <<- TRUE
          }
          )})


m$model
#Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#Formula: math ~ ses * sector + (ses | sch.id)
#   Data: dat
#REML criterion at convergence: 37509.07
#Random effects:
# Groups   Name        Std.Dev. Corr
# sch.id   (Intercept) 1.9053       
#          ses         0.8577   0.46
# Residual             3.1930       
#Number of obs: 7185, groups:  sch.id, 160
#Fixed Effects:
#(Intercept)          ses       sector   ses:sector  
#     11.902        2.399        1.677       -1.322  
#convergence code 0; 0 optimizer warnings; 1 lme4 warnings 

m$error
#[1] TRUE
```

The output `m` is a list with `model` and `error` elements.

---

If we need to test for warning after the model has been created we can use :

```
is_warning_generated <- function(m) {
  df <- summary(m)
  !is.null(df$optinfo$conv$lme4$messages) && 
           grepl('failed to converge', df$optinfo$conv$lme4$messages)
}

m <- lmer(math ~ ses*sector + (ses | sch.id), data = dat)
is_warning_generated(m)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak! So for our logical test, can we write a function where the function gets a model like `m` and outputs `TRUE` if the model has that warning and `FALSE` otherwise?

Comment: Your solution needs the entire model to be retyped inside the list!  Like I said I just need a function that accepts a model object like `m` in my question and checks whether there is that warning (return `TRUE`) or otherwise `FALSE`.

Comment: See updated answer to pass model `m` to function `is_warning_generated`

Answer (score 3):

```
> sm=summary(model)
> sm$optinfo$conv$lme4$messages
[1] "Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0120186 (tol = 0.002, component 1)"
>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what this adds to the existing answers?

Comment: I think that the previous answers are complicated with no apparent reason. Why would one use purrr, grep, write a special function, and all that jazz? It's just a matter of looking at a string in the model object. I read the existing answers and could not figure out what's going on there, at least at the beginning. I think that a simple answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `safely` from `purrr`.  It will also return the `error` as a `list` element and captures the error.  If there are no error, it will be `NULL`

```
library(purrr)
safelmer <- safely(lmer, otherwise = NA)
out <- safelmer(math ~ ses*sector + (ses | sch.id), data = dat)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to say that @RonakShah's `is_warning_generated` could be made slightly more compact:

```r
function(m) { 
    w <- m@optinfo$conv$lme4$messages
    !is.null(w) && grepl('failed to converge', w) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I applied Ronak's solution to my own simulation data and found a problem.
The message may be a vector of multiple entries, leading also `grepl()` to have multiple entries. However, the `&&` operator compares the string only to the first entry, such that further occurrences of 'failed to converge' are unobserved. To avoid this behavior, I changed `&&` to `&`.

Now a problem occurred if there was no message at all. In this case the `!is.null()` part becomes correctly `FALSE` (i.e., no warning generated), but the `grepl()` part becomes `logical(0)` and the function value becomes `FALSE & logical(0)` which is `logical(0)`. In fact it would work for `FALSE && logical(0)` which is `FALSE` (correct).

A solution that worked for me is
`if(is.null(mess)) FALSE else grepl('failed to converge', mess)`

which in case of a failure to converge provides a vector with a TRUE at the entry where the warning was placed. This vector may be evaluated, for example, by building the numeric (or Boolean) sum which becomes greater 0 or TRUE.

Comment: Thanks to Dylan for editing!