# R return object invisibly together with normal error when error is thrown

Tags: r, error-handling

I have a function that may throw an error. When an error is thrown, I'd like to show the error message, as if the error actually occurred, and further return an object invisibly.

I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948361/how-do-i-save-warnings-and-errors-as-output-from-a-function), which uses `withCallingHandlers` and logs the error message somewhere. This comes close, but I do not want to log the message as text and then print a text message, the function should show the error message as if it would have exited on error.

The functions workflow looks like the following:

```
foo <- function(x){

  y <- x + 1
  
    if(y == 2) {
    stop("oops")
    # also return y invisibly when error is thrown,
  }
  
  z <- y + 1
  z
  
}
```

Based on input `x` an intermediate `y` is calculated. `y` is used for the error check. If an error occurs `y` should be returned invisibly and an normal error message should be thrown. Otherwise `z` is calculated an returned.

`foo(1)` should return error message and `y` invisibly.

I thought about using `on.exit` but in this case, always `y` is return invisibly.

Any help is appreciated.

Add: Maybe what I have in mind is not possible. In this case, would it be possible to show a logged error message in a way that comes close to a real error message?

Add2: I thought about issuing a warning, but in my actual use case a `warning` would be misleading, since the function does not produce desired result `z`, but just some intermediate result `y` and I want to return `y` so that the user can inspect it further, and reason about why it wasn't processed correctly by `foo`. Thinking about it, other must have encountered the same problem, there should be some kind of solution.

Add3: Maybe it is possible to use `on.exit` together with a flag which is triggered, so that `on.exit` will return `y` invisibly in case of an error and do nothing otherwise.

Comment: To me, *"throw an error"* means that the function knowingly gives up control, in the premise that it cannot continue. To then return a value is antithetic to that. Is it possible you want to *log* an error and then return something, but with your mention of `withCallingHandlers`, it sounds like that may not be what you need.

Comment: I fear that what I have in mind is not possible. In this case, would it be possible to show the logged error message in a way that comes close to a real error message?

Comment: You can issue a (stern?) `warning`, which is displayed similarly to an error. Since control is not broken, you can warn and then `return`.

Comment: I gave it a thought, but in my actual use case a `warning` would be misleading, since the function does not produce desired result `z`, but just some intermediate result `y` and I want to return `y` so that the user can inspect it further, and reason about why it wasn't processed correctly by `foo`.

Comment: It sounds like your need is to return some object with the error so that the calling environment (human or otherwise) can do something with the object, *knowing* that it is not a good return. Is that right?

Comment: @user: your solution Its getting close, but I am not able to to return `y` invisibly. The console shows ` oops[1] 3` if we could only show `oops` and return `y` invisibly would be great.

Comment: @r2evans: yes exactly.

Comment: sorry deleted my earleir comment due to the invisible... is it enough to do `if(y == 2) {
  tryCatch(stop("oops"), error=function(.)  message(conditionMessage(.)))
  return(invisible(y))   }` . although still not quite right on the error message

Comment: @user20650: Can you post this as an answer? Its good!

Comment: @user20650: Thanks again for your approach! I combined it with r2evans answer and once combined this totally solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```r
func <- function(x) { a <- simpleError("quux"); attr(a,"abc") <- 7; stop(a); }
func()
# Error: quux
```

So far so good, we see an error. If we catch this and look at the contents of the error message we can see the attribute tucked inside:

```r
dput(tryCatch(func(), error=function(e) e))
# structure(list(message = "quux", call = NULL), class = c("simpleError", 
# "error", "condition"), abc = 7)
```

and even extract it easily

```r
dput(tryCatch(func(), error=function(e) attr(e,"abc")))
# 7
```

Comment: So for my function `foo` we would let it return `simpleError: quux>` and then we could create a custom function to inspect that error using `.Last.value`. It's a good approach.

Comment: Thanks again for suggesting `simpleError`. The only thing I had problems with was the "non-standard" error message of `simpleError` which looks different from regular errors. I now used your approach in combination with @user20650's approach (as mentioned in his comments to my question). I posted the final answer below.

Comment: While you're fine to choose whatever works, I do not understand what you mean by "non-standard" error message: we use `simpleError` to generate a structure, add an attribute, and then `stop` with it. That error message looks exactly the same as `stop("quux")` without attributes.

Comment: Maybe I am thinking too complicated. I tried it with `stop` alone, without relying on user20650's workaround, but I wasn't able to achieve the same result as in my answer below. If you can show how to do it with `stop` I gladly accept this answer. The three goals are (i)  foo(1) returns the error message in red just like a regular error, (ii) we can extract the attribute holding `y` from the error and (iii) the result of `foo(1)` should be of class `error` or similar.

Comment: If your solution works, stick with it, I'm not groveling for points. It's an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

Below I post my final solution to my question. Basically it is based on r2evans answer combined with user20650's comment.

As r2evans showed we can use `simpleError` to create an error and also attach an object in the attributes. The big plus of this approach is that it returns a real error that we can program with. If we would only show the error message and then return a vector invisibly, `tryCatch` wouldn't recognize it as an error. The downside is that `simpleError` doesn't look like a normal error to an interactive user when printed in the console. It will show something like `<simpleError: x must not be 1>`. However, the message is not printed in red like normal errors.

Here user20650's comment shows a nice way out. We can first print the message with `message(conditionMessage(e))` and then we can return the `simpleError` invisibly.

```r
foo <- function(x) {
  
  y <- x + 1

  if(y == 2) {
    foo_internal <- function(val) {
      a <- simpleError("x must not be 1")
      attr(a,".data") <- y
      stop(a)
    } 
    return(
      tryCatch(foo_internal(y),
               error = function(e) {
                message(conditionMessage(e))
                invisible(e)
                })
           )
  }
  
  z <- y + 1
  z
  
}

# this is a special function to inspect the object attached to `simpleError`
inspect <- function(x = NULL) {
  if(is.null(x)) {
    x <- .Last.value
  }
  attr(x,".data")
}

# returns error message
foo(1)
#> x must not be 1

# we can get y's value with a special inspect function 
inspect()
#> [1] 2

# foo(1) returns a "real" error
class(foo(1))
#> x must not be 1
#> [1] "simpleError" "error"       "condition"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>