# Capture Error Messages as Character String in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I would like to capture error messages that are returned by my R code in a character string.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948361/how-do-i-save-warnings-and-errors-as-output-from-a-function) explains how to capture error messages of functions. However, when I try to capture the error messages outside of functions, the error message is formatted differently.

Consider the following example R code:

```
5 5
# Error: unexpected numeric constant in "5 5"
```

If I execute the previous R code, the RStudio console returns the error message `Error: unexpected numeric constant in "5 5"`.

However, if I try to capture this output, the error message looks differently:

```
library("evaluate")

evaluate("5 5")[[2]]
# <simpleError: <text>:1:3: unexpected numeric constant
# 1: 5 5
# ^>
```

My expected output is a data object containing the following character string:

```
my_output <- 'Error: unexpected numeric constant in "5 5"'
my_output
# [1] "Error: unexpected numeric constant in \"5 5\""
```

**Question: How could I save the error of an R code as a character string?**

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your response. The expected output is a character string object containing the character string 'Error: unexpected numeric constant in "5 5"'.

Comment: Could you tell us what you need this for? Isn’t this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1968)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you for getting back to me! I try to write a function that updates my R code so that all RStudio console output is shown as a comment within the code. The main purpose is to illustrate my R code and its output on a website. I could copy/paste the error message manually. However, I'm trying to automatize this process.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Unfortunately I don’t see how this would be possible without replicating the logic of `stop` manually. It’s weird that R uses different formats for different types of error (syntax error, logic error that throws), otherwise you could just paste `'Error:'` in front of the `conditionMessage()`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree, I find it very strange. Unfortunately, the more I research about it the more I'm afraid that it is not possible. Anyway, thank you very much for your help Konrad!

Answer (score 2):

> I try to write a function that updates my R code so that all RStudio
> console output is shown as a comment within the code.

I think the [`reprex`](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex) package and R Markdown are doing what you want.

You can test the syntax and combine with [`pander`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pander/pander.pdf) package to deal with errors that occur at the parser level. `pander` does not produce the exact console error but works with `reprex` and R markdown.

***with reprex package***

```
test_eval <- function(text_in){
  if(class(try(parse(text = text_in),silent=TRUE)) == "expression") {
    eval(parse(text = text_in))
  } else {
    x <- pander::evals(text_in)[[1]]$msg$errors
    x <- paste0(tolower(substr(x, 1, 1)), substr(x, 2, nchar(x)))
    x <- paste("Error:", x)
    x <- qdapRegex::rm_between(x, "at", ":", extract=FALSE, replacement="in")
    x <- gsub("` ", "\"", x)
    x <- gsub("`", "\"", x)
    message(x)
  }
}

test_eval("5 5")
#> Error: unexpected numeric constant in "5 5"
test_eval("\"a\" \"a\"")
#> Error: unexpected string constant in ""a" "a""
test_eval("head(iris)")
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
test_eval("list()[[0]]")
#> Error in list()[[0]]: attempt to select less than one element in get1index <real>
test_eval("as.Date(10101)")
#> Error in as.Date.numeric(10101): 'origin' must be supplied
test_eval("library('ggplot2')")
test_eval("data <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = c(3, 1, 6, 3, 5))")
test_eval("ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_line()")
#> Error:   You're passing a function as global data.
#>   Have you misspelled the `data` argument in `ggplot()`
```

***with R Markdown***

````
---
title: Test
output:
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, collapse=TRUE, error=TRUE}
test_eval <- function(text_in){
  if(class(try(parse(text = text_in),silent=TRUE)) == "expression") {
    eval(parse(text = text_in))
  } else {
    message(paste("Error:", pander::evals(text_in)[[1]]$msg$errors))
  }
}

test_eval("5 5")
test_eval("a a")
test_eval("head(iris)")
test_eval("list()[[0]]")
test_eval("as.Date(10101)")
test_eval("library('ggplot2')")
test_eval("data <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = c(3, 1, 6, 3, 5))")
test_eval("ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_line()")
```
````

```
test_eval <- function(text_in){
  if(class(try(parse(text = text_in),silent=TRUE)) == "expression") {
    eval(parse(text = text_in))
  } else {
    x <- pander::evals(text_in)[[1]]$msg$errors
    x <- paste0(tolower(substr(x, 1, 1)), substr(x, 2, nchar(x)))
    x <- paste("Error:", x)
    x <- qdapRegex::rm_between(x, "at", ":", extract=FALSE, replacement="in")
    x <- gsub("` ", "\"", x)
    x <- gsub("`", "\"", x)
    message(x)
  }
}

test_eval("5 5")
## Error: unexpected numeric constant in "5 5"
test_eval("\"a\" \"a\"")
## Error: unexpected string constant in ""a" "a""
test_eval("head(iris)")
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
## 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
## 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
## 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
test_eval("list()[[0]]")
## Error in list()[[0]]: attempt to select less than one element in get1index <real>
test_eval("as.Date(10101)")
## Error in as.Date.numeric(10101): 'origin' must be supplied
test_eval("library('ggplot2')")
test_eval("data <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = c(3, 1, 6, 3, 5))")
test_eval("ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_line()")
## Error:   You're passing a function as global data.
##   Have you misspelled the `data` argument in `ggplot()`
```

`reprex`package and R Markdown are using `evaluate` package. Maybe the test could be done in this package. New issue on Github: https://github.com/r-lib/evaluate/issues/101.

Also opened an issue with `pander`: https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/349.

Regards,

Comment: It's more a limitation than a bug, reprex doesn't handle errors that happen at the parser level, `5 5` is not syntatic code. Following OP's explanations as to why he wants this, it would seem that reprex would be a good choice however, and that he'd be better of fixing the syntax of his code before running the reprex.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thank you for the comment. I updated the message.

Comment: @barboulotte Thank you for the response! This is a nice solution for the types of errors in the first part of your response. Unfortunately, I need a solution for all types of errors, so the `5 5` error is still problematic.

Comment: I updated my message with syntax test and @daroczig pander package to get error at parser level. This works also with R Markdown.

Comment: @barboulotte Thank you for the update. I see two remaining issues: 1) `test_eval("5 5")` still returns a slightly different error message. 2) I'm not able to save the output as character string (e.g. `x <- test_eval("5 5")`).

Comment: The idea is to use it with with reprex or R Markdown. You can try to modify the error message in the function. You can save the output of pander as character string and modify it. `x <- paste("Error:", pander::evals(text_in)[[1]]$msg$errors); ...; message(x)`. I also opened an issue with `pander`: https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/349

Comment: @barboulotte Ah ok I got the idea. I will check it later and let you know if it solved all parts of my problem. I'll assign the bounty points to your answer now, because the bounty is expiring in less than an hour and your answer is definitely the closest to what I was looking for. Thank you very much for all your effort and help!

Comment: Thank you for the bounty. Let know if you succeed. Let see if packages are updated.

Comment: @barboulotte I am now able to save the error messages with your code as character string. Unfortunately, there are still cases where the output is not exactly the same. For example, `test_eval("5 5")` is returning `at character 3 in line 1` in between the original error message.

Comment: Yes, it's the output of pander. I modified the error message in the function.

Comment: @barboulotte Sorry for the late response, and thank you for the updated code. I also hope that the pander package gets updated so that the exact console error is captured, since this would be a cleaner version. However, until then your workaround with the modified output looks fine. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Maybe can you add a thumbs up reaction on the Github issues.

Comment: @barboulotte I think I cannot do that (maybe due to a too low user score, I'm not very active on GitHub).

Answer (score 1):

You could write the code in a temporary file and read it using `Rscript` through a `system` call.
The `intern` option allows to capture the output :

```
tmp <- tempfile()
on.exit(unlink(tmp))
writeLines("5 5",tmp)

err <- suppressWarnings(system(paste('RScript ',tmp),intern = TRUE))
err[1:length(err)-1]
#[1] "Error : unexpected numeric constant in \"5 5\""

print(err)
#[1] "Error : unexpected numeric constant in \"5 5\""
#[2] "Execution stopped"                              
#attr(,"status")
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great solution! I have one issue with your code when I'm dealing with error messages that have more than one line. For example, `writeLines("list()[[0]]",tmp)` is cut off after the first line of error message. Do you maybe know a way how to return the entire error message, no matter how many lines it has? Thanks again, Joachim

Comment: `err` contains all the information, try `print(err)`, see my edit

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! The problem is that I do not know in the forefront how long my error message will be, and I need to extract the entire error message automatically without manually printing the error output stored in err. So I would somehow have to determine automatically the number of vector elements that I have to extract from err to get the entire error message. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: see my edit : I removed the last line of `err` which AFAIK is always `Execution stopped`

Comment: For example, the error message produced by `writeLines("as.Date(10101)", tmp)` also returns `"Calls: as.Date -> as.Date.numeric"`, which is not returned, when I run the line of code manually. Furthermore, there are differences when error messages are returned by packages (e.g. ggplot2). If I run `writeLines("library('ggplot2'); data <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = c(3, 1, 6, 3, 5)); ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_line()", tmp)`, the message `Execution stopped` is not returned at all. Furthermore, the ggplot2 error is split into two lines, which should not be the case.

Comment: @Joachim, I gave the path for a possible solution to this tricky problem, but you'll probably have to handle specific cases like removing "Execution stopped" if it appears, etc...

Comment: OK I see, thank you very much for your help! This is definitely much closer to the final solution compared to what I had before. Thanks a lot for your time!