# Check if columns are renamed when unnesting

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is there a way to know if a table was renamed in the process of unnesting? I want to know if there is something where I can intercept any messages that come through with `New names:` and give more context about solutions

```r
# min reprex
library(tidyverse)

f <- function() { 
  tibble(
    x = 1:2, 
    y = 2:1, 
    z = tibble(x = 1)
  ) |> 
    unnest_wider(z, names_repair = "unique")
}

f()
```

```json
New names:
• `x` -> `x...1`
• `x` -> `x...3`

 x...1     y x...3
 ----- ----- -----
     1     2     1
     2     1     1
```

---

##### More context:

- The message stems from

  ```r
  vctrs::vec_as_names(c("x", "x"), repair = "universal")
  ```
- I see information about [`withCallingHandlers()`](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/conditions.html#handling-conditions) but not sure if that is the right route. I thought there was a way for errors/messages to have classes that you can intercept but I can't remember what I read.
- Something in [`testthat::expect_message()`](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/blob/56d0ad0481c52b86b115cb05971891c04115ff12/R/expect-condition.R#L173-L199) may help. I thought there would be a `has_message()` function out there.
- There is a lot of tidy evaluation and comparing names before and after might be tricky. I could look for the names with the regex  `"\\.+\\d+$"` but not sure that is robust enough since data could have fields with that syntax already.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948361/how-do-i-save-warnings-and-errors-as-output-from-a-function)?

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from [hadley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4963132/11381493), on the question that @ritchie-sacramento linked, you should check out the `evaluate` package.

```r
> eval_res <- evaluate::evaluate("f()")
> eval_res[[2]]$message
[1] "New names:\n* x -> x...1\n* x -> x...3\n"
```

This will require more testing to see what happens to the data structure when there are errors, warnings, or even multiple messages. But this seems like the right track.