# Get exact number of warnings() in R

Tags: r, loops, warnings

I am running a simulation using an iterative algorithm, which should ideally converge at some point. I received numerous warning messages, checked all warnings that were reported and need to report the precise number of warning messages that I got for my choice of convergence criteria.

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

How can I get the exact number of warning messages in R?

Answer (score 2):

You could set `nwarnings` options.

```
options()$nwarnings  ## check current state
# [1] 50

oo <- options(nwarnings=10000)  ## set, store old options

options()$nwarnings  ## check
# [1] 10000

options(oo)  ## restore old options

options()$nwarnings  ## check
# [1] 50
```

However, with this approach you only see how many warnings have occurred (and you probably need to set `nwarnings` even higher).

In simulation studies you might be interested in which cases the warning occurred. So, alternatively think about storing the warning together with the respective replication. See [this nice Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948361/how-do-i-save-warnings-and-errors-as-output-from-a-function) here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ jay.sf: Thanks! Setting `nwarnings` higher can be done like this: `options(nwarnings = 1000)`. This worked for me anyways.

Comment: @R-ista yeah was a typo thanks for spotting

Answer (score 1):

You can capture each warning message in a vector using `withCallingHandlers`. The following loop for example should emit 66 warnings:

```r
for(i in 1:66) {
  b <- as.numeric('a')
}
#> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

But we can catch an indefinite number of warnings if we wrap run our code with a calling handler:

```r
warn_msgs <- character()

for(i in 1:66) {
  
  withCallingHandlers(
  {
    b <- as.numeric('a')
  },
  warning = function(w) warn_msgs <<- append(warn_msgs, w$message)
  )
}
#> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

length(warn_msgs)
#> [1] 66
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I just ask: `<<- append(warn_msgs, w$message)` should be  `<- append(warn_msgs, w$message)`?

Comment: @R-ista no, that doesn't work. You need the `<<-` operator so that `warn_msgs` is written to in the global environment. Otherwise it would be treated as local to the function.