R: How to install packages in a loop and store error messages of all that couldn't be installed?
How can I extend this code to store installation status messages in addition to names of packages? I want to use verbose = TRUE to minimize amount of output and not show any message if installation was succesfull.
packages_lst <- c("dplyr", "xlsx", "zoo")

missing <- c()
for (pkg in packages_lst){
  install.package(pkg, verbose = TRUE) 
  if !(pkg %in% installed.packages()){
     message(paste("Installation failed for ", pkg)
     missing <- c(missing, pkg)}
}

message(paste("Finished. Failed to install packages: ", paste(missing, collapse = ","))

(Yes, I know I could simplify this code and just print difference between packages_lst and installed.packages() with no need to create missing variable, but it is here to store status messages.)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952908/1412059
